# Sending image to Django Rest in Visual studio Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, visual-studio, post, xamarin

I stuck with a one problem in Visual Studio while i create an app for Android. I try to send some data (id, key and image) to the webservice (Django REST framework) and get a response. The code look like that

```
string requestUri = "https://www.haremtravel.com/api/new";
requestItem item = new requestItem(itemType,itemKey);
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(item);
byte[] b = SystemIO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
HttpContent stringContent = new StringContent(json);
HttpContent fileByteContent = new ByteArrayContent(b);    
var formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();
formData.Add(stringContent);
formData.Add(fileByteContent);
HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
var responseObj = httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, formData);
```

Result is "StatusCode:500, ReasonPhrase:'Internal Server Error',Version 1.1, Content:System.Net.Http.StreamContent,Headers:"
If i use something simple, for example html/php form with 2 text inputs and 1 file inputs (or plugin for Chrome "Postman") - it works. 
Can anybody help me with this issue, please?

---

**--UPDATED--**

requestItem class

```
public class requestItem
{
    public int gameid;
    public string key;
    public requestItem(int newId, string newKey)
    {
        gameid = newId;
        key = newKey;
    }
}
```

Screenshot of request in Postman
[postman request](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fILIL.jpg)

Comment: Hi, could you add the code for `requestItem`class / struct? Does the endpoint expect the request to be a `MultiPartForm`? It would help if you added a screenshot of the request you make in postman.

Comment: Have you tried this Post request outside the App, using third parties Rest request clients like Postman?

Comment: To @woelliJ Hi. requestItem is a simple class with 2 fields - int id and string key. I added screenshot of request in postman

Comment: To @apineda Hi. Yes. I tried it in Postman. It shows correct result

Comment: @AdeptusMechanicus i'm afraid i can't see the screenshot. And if you don't post the code for your `requestItem` class i can't say whether it is a problem at serialization

Comment: @woelliJ Can you look once more? It at the end of main text under the --UPDATED-- title

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for updating your question with the relevant information.

It's not necessary to serialize your data-object (the data class itself is redundant if you're not using it any other way)

Try it with this code:

```
        string requestUri = "https://www.haremtravel.com/api/new";
        requestItem item = new requestItem(itemType, itemKey);

        byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);

        MultipartFormDataContent formData = new MultipartFormDataContent();

        formData.Add(new StringContent(item.gameid.ToString()), "gameid");
        formData.Add(new StringContent(item.key), "key");
        formData.Add(new ByteArrayContent(b, 0, b.Count()), "image");

        HttpClient httpClient = new HttpClient();
        var responseObj = httpClient.PostAsync(requestUri, formData);
```

---

Uploading the file:

Try adding the ContentType Header with:

```
byte[] b = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filePath);
var imageContent = new ByteArrayContent(b);
imageContent.Headers.ContentType = MediaTypeHeaderValue.Parse("image/jpeg");

formData.Add(imageContent, "image");
```

maybe you have to additionally add the file's name

```
string fileName = GetFileNameWithExtensionSomehow(filePath);
formData.Add(imageContent, "image", fileName);
```

Comment: Thank you. It works partially (not a Internal server error). Now response is {"image": ["Sent data is not a file. Check the type of coding on the form."]} I tried formData.Add(new StreamContent(new SystemIO.FileStream(filePath, SystemIO.FileMode.Open)), "image"); but it doesn't work too. I'll be appreciated if you'll help me with this too.

Comment: i'm glad i could help. feel free to mark my answer as the 'correct' one ;)